# PharData compress nests original tar

Tags: php, gzip, tar, phar

Maybe it is intended but i find it weird that "PharData compress" nests the original tar inside of the compressed tar.gz. So you have to open the .tar.gz and you will see the original.tar which you have to open again?

Code:

```
    $tarPath  = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'api/sample2.tar';
    $pharData = new PharData( $tarPath  );
    $pharData->addFile( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'api/callback_post.txt', 'callback_post.txt' );
    $pharData->compress(Phar::GZ);
```

Php 7.4

Answer (score 0):

These are two diferent concepts. Tar packs files, while gz compress tar package.

You may try ZipArchive

```
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$zip->open($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'api/sample2.zip')
$zip->addFile($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'api/callback_post.txt', 'callback_post.txt');
$zip->close();
```

Comment: Well yeah but i simply want a tar.gz with all the files on the first layer, not the tar file inside the tar.gz.

Comment: I have to send a tar.gz, so a zip is not a valid alternative.

Comment: Chris Kerngebiet if you have to use .tar.gz i guess you must respect .tar.gz format.

Comment: If code you wrote is working all is ok. Your question looks like you think .tar.gz behavior is strange, but just is like it works.